# navigate to localhost than domain login github single authentication spring

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, dns, localhost, single-sign-on

i follow bellow link up test single sign on.
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

[image: navigate to github.com/login not localhost:8080/login]

I open home page "/" it will foreword me to localhost:8080/login i want this to go login to github.com/login.
i want my application to login through github credentials.

i am using spring with maven and test simple authentication by one click. when you login in gmail you can open linked website and by one click you login to linked using gmail credentials or access tokens

i want my application to login through github credentials.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your reply it was a version dependency issue using OpenJDK issue is solved.

Answer (score 2):

We should use openJDK.
Kindly find below steps

1. https://spring.io/quickstart > use java 8 and add web dependencies download zip
2. download and install eclipse
3. download Java Development Kit JDK from recommended spring.io/quickstart website not Java from Oracle official website.